# Different order by clause for different columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I hope my title made sense, here's a sample of my table.

My table has 1 column for a unique product barcode, and 4 date columns which is for storing what date and time a product passed an inspection area(4 of them), i removed the date in my example so just assume they're all the same dates.

```
Product | Time1 | Time2 | Time3 | Time4
---------------------------------------
   A    | 10:00 | 10:15 | 10:30 | 10:45
   B    | 10:05 | 10:25 | 10:35 | 10:50
   C    | 10:10 | 10:20 | 10:40 | 10:55
```

Output:

```
 Inspect1 | Inspect2 | Inspect3 | Inspect4
 -----------------------------------------
    A            A         A          A
    B            C         B          B
    C            B         C          C
```

In my output, I want to select the product multiple times with different order by(order by Time1, order by Time2, etc.)

I used case select to select the product multiple times, how do I put an order by so that I get something like my example above.

```
SELECT     
CASE WHEN time1 BETWEEN '10:00' AND '11:00' THEN product END AS inspect1, 
CASE WHEN time2 BETWEEN '10:00' AND '11:00' THEN product END AS inspect2, 
CASE WHEN time3 BETWEEN '10:00' AND '11:00' THEN product END AS inspect3, 
CASE WHEN time4 BETWEEN '10:00' AND '11:00' THEN product END AS inspect4
FROM         Table
```

Comment: Check pivot :https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: Your question is unclear, can you elaborate on your expected result?

Comment: @wewesthemenace My output is just the Product column but selected multiple times with different order by. The first one is Order by the column Time1 then the next is order by the column Time2, etc.

Comment: use case also in order by clause like you use in select statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `ROW_NUMBER`:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/554a1/1/0)

```
WITH CteUnion(Product, TimeNum, Value) AS(
    SELECT Product, 'Time1', Time1 FROM YourTable UNION ALL
    SELECT Product, 'Time2', Time2 FROM YourTable UNION ALL
    SELECT Product, 'Time3', Time3 FROM YourTable UNION ALL
    SELECT Product, 'Time4', Time4 FROM YourTable
),
CteRN AS(
    SELECT *,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TimeNum ORDER BY Value)
    FROM CteUnion
),
CteOrd AS(
    SELECT *,
        Ord = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY RN ORDER BY Value)
    FROM CteRN
)
SELECT
    Inspect1 = MAX(CASE WHEN Ord = 1 THEN Product END),
    Inspect2 = MAX(CASE WHEN Ord = 2 THEN Product END),
    Inspect3 = MAX(CASE WHEN Ord = 3 THEN Product END),
    Inspect4 = MAX(CASE WHEN Ord = 4 THEN Product END)
FROM CteOrd
GROUP BY RN
ORDER BY RN
```

Comment: Thank you, is there anything you recommend I can read for making queries like this. Honestly I can't come up with something like this on my own.

Comment: Try searching for the blogs of these people: Aaron Bertrand, Erland Sommarskog, Jeff Moden, Gail Shaw, etc. =)